# Adding one array into another array but at equal intervals

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My code is currently like this:

```
paynowString = "00020101021126380009SG.PAYNOW010100211+658128992803010520400005303702545800.005802SG59006009Singapore620401006304"

characters = []

def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

characters = split(paynowString)
print(characters)

ascii_characters = [ord(char) for char in characters]
print(ascii_characters)

x_domain = np.zeros(4200)
x_domain[2110:] = ascii_characters
```

where I am trying add the entries in ascii_characters into x_domain. However, I'm trying to add them in intervals of 5. This means that  if the ascii_characters is:

```
[a b c d e f g .....]
```

Then the x_domain will be:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 a 0 0 0 0 b 0 0 0 0 c .....]
```

where the 6th, 11th, 16th elements of x_domain will be elements from ascii_characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
res=[]
x=list(x_domain)

for i in range(len(ascii_characters)):
    res=res+x[i*4:(i*4+4)]+[ascii_characters[i]]
res=res+x[(i+1)*4:]

res=np.array(res)

>>>print(res[:30])
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 48, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 48, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 48, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 48, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 49]
```